# Looking to pass all props using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is there a simple way to pass all props of a parent component to a child component when using hooks?

It seems to get repetitive sending each state to each component.

I'm wondering if spread operator works and if so what the proper syntax is?

*I apologize for not providing an example, had to leave. The example is something to what I'm doing.*

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [count, setcount] = useState(0)
    const [example, setExample] = useState('')

    return (
        <Child props={...How to pass all props in the state} 
    )
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are doing now, so we can understand what your problem is.

Comment: I suspect it is "**state** of a parent" instead of "props of a parent". If it is "props" then the provided answer is enough for the solution. If you keep the state piece that you will pass the children as an object you can use spread operator. Other than that if you keep each state piece in a separate variable then you should pass them individually.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). It was implemented for the same purpose (when passing props down the children's components).

Also, you can do something like below for the class components:

```
<SomeComponent {...this.props} />
```

and for functional components:

```
<SomeComponent {...props} />
```